# Rails: How to get the controller & method name of Restfull named routes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-3.1

In my HTML View

```
<% if check_link(dashboard_path) %>
  <%= link_to "Products", dashboard_path, class: controller_name == "dashboard" ? "active" : nil %>
<% end %>
```

In check_link helper method:

```
  def check_link(path)
    controller_name = path.controller
    method_name = path.action

    then i have some extra access verification code ............

  end
```

But, I am getting error like below in the browser:

> undefined method `controller' for "/admin/dashboard":String

Now, My question is how to find the controller and method name from the "Named routes(dashboard_path)". Please someone help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Rails.application.routes.recognize_path` for extracting your `:controller` and `:action`

```
def check_link(path)
  extracted_path =  Rails.application.routes.recognize_path(path)


  controller = extracted_path[:controller]
  action = extracted_path[:action]

  # your rest of the codes goes here
end
```

**Example**

```
Rails.application.routes.recognize_path('/parties/autocomplete_party_name_last', {:method => :get})

# Output will be    
{:action=>"autocomplete_party_name_last", :controller=>"parties"}

OR 

Rails.application.routes.recognize_path('/transcriptions/2/edit')

# Output will be    
=> {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"transcriptions", :id=>"2"}
```

If your path is incorrect then you will get something like this:

```
Rails.application.routes.recognize_path('dashboards/index')

# output will be
=> {:controller=>"pages", :action=>"page_not_found", :url=>"dashboards/index"}
```

Hope you find this useful.

Comment: If this solution works for you, then can you ```accept``` this answer :)

Answer (score 0):

ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet#recognize_path

this may help. This will give to which controller action the path is mapped.

Answer (score 0):

```
Rails.application.routes.recognize_path('/my_path')
```

Answer (score -1):

dashboard_path is a string so you can't call #controller and #action methods on it. try just controller_name and method_name. alternatively params[:controller] and params[:action]

Comment: we can do params[:controller] once after click that link , but how do i find the controller name from named routes ..

Answer (score -1):

The `params` hash will always contain the `:controller` and `:action` keys, you can try this

```
def check_link(path)
    controller_name = params[:controller]
    method_name = params[:action]
end
```

Comment: we can do params[:controller] once after click that link , but how do i find the controller name from named routes ...